# Django Admin Fk grouping

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

How do I go about grouping a set of fields within the Django Admin. By this I mean

Table 1: User - User Key - User Name

Table 2: Post - Post Key - User Key (FK)

In the PostAdmin I would like to display the User Name of the Author also perform an action on the posts. This works but displays the user name for each post created by the user.

Is there a way I could just display the user name once but in the action update all posts created by the user? - Update all posts with is_sealed = true.

Model

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_("email address"), unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(
                 _("first name"), max_length=50,
                 validators=[RegexValidator(
                     regex_alpha, code='invalid_first_name',
                     message=regex_alpha_message,
                 )]
    )
    middle_name = models.CharField(
                  _("middle name"), max_length=50, blank=True,  
                  null=True, default=None,
                  validators=[RegexValidator(
                             regex_alpha, code='invalid_middle_name',
                             message=regex_alpha_message,
                  )]
    )

class Post(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    title = models.CharField(_('title'), max_length=250)
    label = models.ForeignKey(Label, verbose_name=_('label'))
    significance = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=SIGNIFICANCE_CHOICES)
    is_sealed = models.BooleanField(_('Is Sealed?'), default=False)
    event_date = models.DateField()
    message = models.TextField(_("Message"), blank=True, default='')
```

PostAdmin (I need to fix the issue here)

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['owner','is_sealed']
    ordering = ['owner']
    actions = [open_vault]
    search_fields = ['owner__email',]
    list_filter = ['owner__email']
```

Comment: What do you mean `display the user name once`? In your code, right now, each row (entry) should display the `owner`.

Comment: I just want the owner to be displayed once if the owner has 10 posts or 1 post. basically group by the owner

Comment: So, you want **each row** in `list_display` to include all posts grouped by author. Right? If that's so, why don't use the filters on the right by filtering posts by author?

Comment: there will be lots of users so filtering may not be the best user experience

Answer (score 0):

So, according to your comments, you must write a custom method inside `UserAdmin` for displaying posts related to a user/author, like this:

```
from django.utils.html import mark_safe

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['email', 'get_posts']
    # ... other settings here

    def get_posts(self, obj):
        to_return = '<ul>'
        for post in obj.post_set.all():
            to_return += '<li>{}</li>'.format(post.title)
        to_return += '</ul>'
        return mark_safe(to_return)
```